# How to solve symbolic function like this in R

Tags: r

This should be simple for those with experience.
I want to solve an equation using R. I know you can solve 
different linear/quadratic equations using Solve().

But I have something like this:

```
1/20 = 1/8 * (1/(12+x)) + 1/4*(1/(40+x)) + 3/4*(1/(50+x))
```

How can I solve x in this case? It can't be done by hand.
It gotta be some numeric methods involved to solve this like in TI83.

Is there a simple and quick way to do this in R without writing lines of codes?
Thank you!

Comment: Take a look to the [Ryacas package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Ryacas/), it may be helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, there are indeed roots. First thing is to plot the function:

```
f <- function(x) {1/20 - 1/8 * (1/(12+x)) + 1/4*(1/(40+x)) + 3/4*(1/(50+x))}
x <- seq(-100,100)
par(mar=c(2,2,1,2))     # this just minimizes plot margins
plot(x,f(x), type="l")
abline(0,0,col="blue",lty=2)
```

[image]

So obviously, `f(x)` does cross 0, several times.

Next step is to estimate the crossings. One way to do this is to look for changes in sign:

```
x <- seq(-75,0,0.001)
y <- sign(f(x))                     # vector of +1 or -1
plus.to.minus <- which(diff(y)<0)   # diff(y)<0 when f crosses from (+) to (-)
minus.to.plus <- which(diff(y)>0)   # diff(y)>0 when f crosses from (-) to (+)
# first two roots are (+) to (-); third is (-) to (+)
lower <- c(plus.to.minus[1:2],minus.to.plus[3])
roots <- sapply(lower,function(i)uniroot(f,interval=c(x[i],x[i+1]))$root)
lapply(roots,function(x) points(roots,c(0,0,0),col="red",pch=16))
roots
# [1] -67.38961 -41.72593 -10.38446
```

[image]

This code attempts to find `x` where `f(x)` changes sign. There are actually two reasons that `f(x)` could change sign: a root, or an asymptote. In your case there are three roots, and three asymptotes. Success here depends on having a small enough increment in x so that you don't completely miss a crossing. Based in the graph above it looks like 0.001 is small enough.

Here, `y` is a vector which contains the sign of f (as +1 or -1) at `x` between -75 and 0, in increments of 0.001. The limits (-75,0) were chosen by inspecting the plot above. We can see visually that there are three roots. The first two cross from (+) to (-), and the third crosses from (-) to (+). So we identify the index of x where the crossings occur (using `which(...)`), and then create a vector that contains the first two elements of `plus.to.minus` and the third element of `minus.to.plus`. Then we call `uniroot(...)` using `increment=c(x[i],x[i+1])` where `i` is the index of the appropriate crossing.

Finally, we plot the results to confirm that we have in fact found the roots. This is really important - always, *always* plot the results. It turns out that `uniroot(...)` will find a "root" where there is an asymptote, so you have to make sure you've found actual roots.

Comment: thank you! you have to add $root at the end to indicate that we're looking for answers around the roots?

Comment: Look at the documentation for `uniroot(...)`. It returns a list with several elements; `uniroot$root` is the value of the root. `uniroot$f.root` is the value of the function at the root (close to, but not quite 0), and so on.

Comment: I saw you edited your post. I sort of understand that you did there. But your previous editing was much simpler. If I only do this uniroot(f,c(-100,100))$root, this doesn't work. I've seen some other examples simply using this. Where is my mistake?

Comment: It turns out that my previous answer was too simplistic. See the edits above. To answer you comment directly, `uniroot(...)` expects that `f` will have a different sign at the two limits. Otherwise it throws an error. You can see from the plot that `f(-100)` and `f(100)` are both positive.

Comment: very nice answer! Thank you again for your work! Guess the numeric method in uniroot is kinda finicky. You have to make it right to get the correct answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use `uniroot()` to solve equations in one variable:

```
f <- function(x){
  1/8 * (1/(12+x)) + 1/4*(1/(40+x)) + 3/4*(1/(50+x)) - 1/20
}
uniroot(f, interval = c(-1e+08, 1e+08))
```

Notice that in the function, `f`, I subtract `1/20`.  This is because `uniroot()` finds the zero of the function.

In this case, you will get the error:

```
Error in uniroot(f, interval = c(-1e+08, 1e+08)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

To correct this, you need to make sure the zero exists and if it does, move the interval, (a, b) so that f(a) == -f(b)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Why is there a error in your output? I tried and got the same thing. What's the problem here, even if I set it equal to zero for the function?

Comment: It is because there is no solution for the zero in that interval.  You need to make sure the zero exists and if it does, move the interval, `(a, b)` so that `f(a) == -f(b)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a solution to another function I have. It still gives me this error.

Comment: Try plotting... tmp <- data.frame(x=-50:50, y=f(-50:50)); qplot(x,y, data=tmp); You'll see there are a couple of zeros.. For example: uniroot(f,c(-10, 10))